# No callback from Play Billing Library 3 to confirm the purchase

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

We are implementing in-app purchase for Android using Java. I have added the required implementations and followed this guide: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate.
I am however not getting a callback in onQueryPurchasesFinished, so I don't know if the purchases are finished. This worked in earlier IAP versions. I am a paid user according to Google's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem was that we started with the wrong approach. The consultant who worked on this had already build a library for Billing Library 1. He then tried to adapt and customize that library for Billing Library 3. That did not work. It would have been better to delete the old library and start over again. We got everything to work when we did that.